# campos y valor de url

Tags: javascript, url

tengo esta url:

```
http://localhost/pagina.php?grado=2&escuela=urbano
```

Quiero poder tomar los campos grado y escuela con sus valores y colocarlos en una variable llamada datos como puedo hacer eso, ya intente varias formas pero me marca error

Comment: edita la pregunta y publica tu codigo para corregir lo que tengas mal.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes obtener la url actual con `window.location.href`, luego apoyarte en la clase URL para extraer los parámetros:

```js
var url = new URL('http://localhost/pagina.php?grado=2&escuela=urbano');
var grado = url.searchParams.get('grado');
console.log(grado);
```